# Can we find a way to link new users to /help/someone-answers when they receive an answer for the first time?

Tags: feature-request, new-users

When a new user gets an answer, often they don't know what to do with it. They post "thanks" comments, get into discussions, and don't accept / upvote. This is why users will sometimes avoid answering questions by new users.

This isn't good, on either side.

But what if we could help mitigate this problem? Basically, by linking the /help/someone-answers page to the clueless new users. The /help/someone-answers page explains what we expect here on SE, and it's a useful page. The problem is that new users have no way of finding it. It'd require the to trawl through the help center - not the easiest to find  - and stumbling across that page.

But what if we could link it to them right when they need it?

Is there any way that we could show the user a message about this *when they get an answer for the first time*? e.g. a banner "You've just received an answer for the first time! Please check out [/help/someone-answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to see what we expect of you when you recieve an answer to your question."

Would this be possible in any way?

Comment: Show a noti item in the inbox? That sounds good to me.

Comment: I made the [same question](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3529/120647) today in GDSE with another possible solution.

Answer (score 5):

Why stop with the /help/someone-answers?

I'm a new user here and I had a *very* hard time finding the help center and all the rules that one need to follow. And I *wanted* to find them. I'm that kind of person who read every user guide before doing anything in a new "internet place". Not knowing the explicit rules make me stress and tend to prevent me from answering, comment or ask a question.

If I had so much trouble finding these rules, people who don't care as much will just stop trying to find them and do whatever.

So, I think a clear link to something similar to [this response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314695/400547) would be good.

Comment: Sure, ideally I'd like to have a link to the appropriate help center page whenever it's possible for new users. (Also, new users get a clear link to the tour and the tour has a link to the help center at the bottom, but that's still not super discoverable.)